# translating some hash code from .net syntax to objective-c

Tags: ios, iphone, .net, objective-c, sha1

I'm trying to translate some hashcode that is written with `.NET` into `Objective-c` Syntax

```
SHA1 sha1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
   string hashedword = Convert.ToBase64String(sha1.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(saltkey)))
```

This is what I have so far

```
NSData *data = [password dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *unicodePassword = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding];
    data = [unicodePassword dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding];
    unsigned char hash[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    CC_SHA1([data bytes], [data length], hash);
    NSData *result = [NSData dataWithBytes:hash length:CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];
```

At the end I want an `hashed NSString`.

Can somebody help me with this ?

Comment: Among other things the suggestion you change to UTD8 encoding is something to really consider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NSUnicodeStringEncoding` conversions look suspicious in your code and seem
to be unnecessary. You have to use the same encoding as your .NET code.

I cannot test this with .NET, but
according to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.text.encoding.ascii%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), `Encoding.ASCII` uses the
replacement character `?` for all non-ASCII characters.

There is no equivalent `NSStringEncoding`, but the same result 
can be achieved with CoreFoundation methods:

```
NSString *password = ... // your password

CFIndex asciiLength;
// Determine length of converted data:
CFStringGetBytes((__bridge CFStringRef)(password), CFRangeMake(0, [password length]),
                 kCFStringEncodingASCII, '?', false, NULL, 0, &asciiLength);
// Allocate buffer:
uint8_t *asciiBuffer = malloc(asciiLength);
// Do the conversion:
CFStringGetBytes((__bridge CFStringRef)(password), CFRangeMake(0, [password length]),
                 kCFStringEncodingASCII, '?', false, asciiBuffer, asciiLength, NULL);
```

Now you can compute the SHA1 hash:

```
unsigned char hash[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];
CC_SHA1(asciiBuffer, asciiLength, hash);
free(asciiBuffer);
NSData *result = [NSData dataWithBytes:hash length:CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];
```

And finally the Base64-encoded string from the hash. Starting with iOS 7,
there is a built-in method:

```
NSString *base64 = [result base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
```

A better option would be to use the UTF-8 encoding instead of ASCII encoding
(for both .NET and Objective-C).
In that case the code would simplify to

```
NSData *data = [password dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
unsigned char hash[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];
CC_SHA1([data bytes], [data length], hash);
NSData *result = [NSData dataWithBytes:hash length:CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];
NSString *base64 = [result base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
```

If the password contains only ASCII characters, both methods give the same result.

Answer (score 0):

If you need that final base-64 string, you can use this code, which either calls the new iOS 7 `base64EncodedStringWithOptions` or calls the now deprecated (and previously private) `base64Encoding` method in earlier versions:

```
NSString *string;

if ([data respondsToSelector:@selector(base64EncodedStringWithOptions:)]) {
    string = [result base64EncodedStringWithOptions:kNilOptions];  // iOS 7+
} else {
    string = [result base64Encoding];                              // pre iOS7
}
```